# StreamWriter all lines to file

Tags: c#, linq, streamwriter

**C#**
I have a console app that reads and writes a get/set list of "Person" details. It works correctly up until I try to write it to a text file as well. Can somebody tell me why this  writes the last line of "Person" details into my text file instead of the whole list?

```
        loadData();

        Console.WriteLine("All People");
        //1st query - just select all people
        var queryAllPeople = from person in people  select person;

        foreach (Person p in queryAllPeople)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("people.txt"))
            {

                writer.WriteLine(p);

            }
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I'm guessing that "writer.WriteLine(p)" is incorrect but I can't figure out what's wrong with it

Comment: probably it overwrites the previous written lines. Would be better I think to do the foreach within the using streamwriter.

Comment: maybe using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("people.txt", true) ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Put the foreach inside the using statement.  You are overwriting the file at every iteration of your loop

Answer (score 7):

You are writing a new file with the same name for each iteration. You will want to create the `StreamWriter` outside of the loop instead:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("people.txt"))
{
    foreach (Person p in queryAllPeople)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(p);
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(p);` still needs to live inside the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 4):

You are re-creating the file every time. Try:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("people.txt"))
{
    foreach (Person p in queryAllPeople)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(p);
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the overload to [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) that accepts append as a parameter so you append the 
value to the file each time.

```
foreach (Person p in queryAllPeople)
{
  using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("people.txt", true))
  {

     writer.WriteLine(p);

  }
  Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

Or just wrap the foreach in a the `using` statement.